# where to put mongos on AWS to ensure High Availability

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, distributed, high-availability

I have a mongos to route my queries to two different mongo clusters running on two different ec2 instances so that if one ec2 instance goes down, i have a backup.

The challenge is, where should I put my mongos query router? I do not want to put my mongos query router on a 3rd EC2 instance upstream, because EC2 instances can fail and break. I've had this happen to me. Ec2 instances do not recover on their own and spin themselves up again right?. If the ec2 instance that my mongos query router is on goes down, then all the redundancy upstream that is built for high-availability becomes irrelevant.

So is there another amazon service (like an ec2) that is small, and would only be dedicated to one server (a mongos query distributor), that can spin itself up again if it goes down due to hardware failures, or auto-grow its own RAM and disk-space to give the mongos query router more resources due to software consuming system resources?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ec2 instances can auto-recover now via

```
  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-auto-recovery-for-amazon-ec2/
```

So having a mongos query router on a mini ec2 instance with auto-scaling and auto-recovery should be safe.

Also, though not an out-of-box solution for ec2 instances, it looks like you can now also scale up the RAM and disk-size of your ec2 instance by using custom cloud-watch alarms to trigger these actions via

```
 http://aws.amazon.com/code/8720044071969977
```